# How to fix slow issue when using async and await for caching using Sqflite?

Tags: dart, flutter

I store all API data to cache. some APIs have more than 10000 data. Postman response time is within one second. but in application very slow to navigate to next page. I used this code:

```
    onPressed: () async {
    ...
    }   
     else {
var token = Token(
                                      id: 1,
                                      token: tokens,
                                      refreshToken: model.data.refreshToken,
                                    );
                                     await storeRegister(_url,tokens);
                                     await storeEquipmentReg(_url,tokens);
                                     await storeSyncLogin(_url,tokens);
                                     await HelperDefCatMaster().deleteDefCatMaster();
                                     await storeDefCatMaster(_url,tokens);
                                     await HelperDefRegisterCat().deleteDefRegisterCat();
                                     await storeDefRegisterCat(_url,tokens);
                                     await HelperDefCatMaster().deleteDefCatRelation();
                                     await storeDefCatRelation(_url,tokens);
                                     await HelperDefCatMaster().deleteWoDescription();
                                      await storeWoDescription(_url,tokens);
                                     await HelperDefCatMaster().deleteCategoryDefect();
                                     await storeCategoryDefect(_url,tokens);
                                     await storeWorkSource(_url,tokens);
                                     await storeWorkTypes(_url,tokens);
                                     await storePriorities(_url,tokens);
                                    await Helper().insert(token);
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => ListPage(model.data.token)));
                                  }
```

storePriorities function look like,

```
storePriorities(String url, String token) async {
  final response = await http.get(
    '${url}/v1.0/Priorities',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'},
  );
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  Priorities model = Priorities.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  int length = model.data.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var data = DataPriorities(
      i: model.data[i].i,
      d: model.data[i].d,
    );
    await HelperDefCatMaster().insertPriorities(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is HelperDefCatMaster?

Comment: it is database helper. create a database and create tables and display values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have given the first answer that suggests to use `await` only when it's needed.*

Well if you are inserting too much data in SQLite I assume that you might be using something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
  db.insert('table_name', dataObject.toMap());
}
```

Well this will do a lot many transactions at a time and it will consume a lot's of your time.

Change this to something like this and it will increase the speed of inserting data:

```
Batch batch = db.batch();
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
  batch.insert('table_name', dataObject.toMap());
}
await batch.commit();
```

What we are doing here is that, in single transaction we are doing multiple inserts at a time.

I made this change in my demo project where I was inserting 1000 row at a time and results were great. db.insert when called 1000 times took 7 secs where as batch.insert took less than 1 sec for inserting same amount of data.

If you optimize your code with this solution and use await when needed you should not face any problem on UI. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: wow..It's working well. after QA checking I will let you know actual result

Comment: @kapesh, can I use a transaction for getting the data? I mean will it be a faster operation?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using `await` keyword to fetch data from SQLite.
2. And you are fetching a lots of data.
3. This will make data fetching synchronous, and will affect your UI.
4. If it is convenient for your use-case to fetch data asynchronously then you can use the following way:

Change :

```
await Helper().insert(token);
Navigator.push(
    context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListPage(model.data.token)));
```

to :

```
Helper().insert(token).then((onValue) {
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ListPage(model.data.token),
      ),
    );
}
```

Note: Make your `insert` method return `Future<'token's return type'>`

Now use this way for all other `await` calls.

Comment: how to these things: ```await storeWoDescription(_url,tokens);
                            await HelperDefCatMaster().deleteCategoryDefect();
                            await storeCategoryDefect(_url,tokens);
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          ListPage(model.data.token)));```

Comment: how to use all other await calls?

Comment: The key thing is to not to use await when you don't wan't to do synchronous operation.. are these all await call needed to execute in order ??

Comment: no, but data is missing when navigator to next page.

Comment: after navigating next page and waiting 10 minutes data is coming

Comment: I showed the progress bar. but you know client doesn't like to waiting 10minutes

Comment: If it is taking 10 mins for you to complete the process then you may want to change your approach to save data.. 1 thing you can do is make a repository class and keep data in variables, navigate to next page and read data from those variables. and in background sync that data to database. I hope I am clear.. if not then please let me know..